# Is there a way to have Java print all of the decimal places in a number, rather than showing it in scientific notation?

Tags: java

I'm trying to profile the inside of a function to see which allocations are taking the longest. Each individual operation is quite tiny, thus I'm using `System.nanoTime()` to gather all elapsed times. Being that these times are super small, Java prints out their numbers in scientific notation, which is fine, I'd just rather see the full number so I can quickly compare a set of numbers without having to look back and forth between their exponents.

#### Code Setup:

```
System.out.println("Time to taken to allocate data: " + 
                       (System.nanoTime() - startTime)/1000000000.0);
```

#### Code output:

```
Time taken to allocate: 5.7987E-4
```

I would prefer, if possible, the output to look like this:

```
Time taken to allocate: 0.00057987
```

A bit trivial, but it would make it a bit easier for me to quickly parse.

Comment: That's a `double`, not a `long`.

Comment: you can use `String.format()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
System.out.printf("Time to taken to allocate data: %.8f%n", 
                                   (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1E9);
```

which rounds the result to 8 decimal places (should be enough).

---

To see the difference:

```
double d = 5.7987E-4;
System.out.println("Time to taken to allocate data: " + d);
System.out.printf("Time to taken to allocate data: %.8f%n", d);
```

```
Time to taken to allocate data: 5.7987E-4
Time to taken to allocate data: 0.00057987
```

Answer (score -1):

For timing code, my preferred solution is the Profiler class provided by SLF4J extensions:
http://www.slf4j.org/extensions.html#profiler

Comment: Good, but doesn't answer the immediate question.